# How to get Coordinate axis (x,y) parallel to orientation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins

I am using QGIS 2.14.11. I have a map with drains as you can see on the map. I would like the coordinate (x,y) of each point but my origin point (at the corner just below in red on the map) will be (0,0). The x axis will be parallel at the length and y axis parallel to the width as you can see on the image.

Do you know how that could be done?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here need to be as complete as possible. In this case that means clarifying where you got the "map" (it looks like an image to me), if it is georeferenced, what coordinate system it is in, and what you have tried. GIS SE works better with "I've tried this and got stuck" questions than with, "Tell me how to start" ones.